# I am not able to plot mean line over my bar graph which I made using unstack method

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, mean

```
total_group_sum.unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

I am able to plot my bar graph, however now I want to draw a horizontal mean line over it. I try using `axhline()` but I am getting an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How do I plot a horizontal mean line over my already existing bar graph?

```
total_group_sum.unstack().plot(kind='bar')

<IMAGE OF BAR GRAPH (I AM NOT ABLE TO POST PHOTO HERE)>

mean = total_group_sum.mean()
plt = total_group_sum.unstack().plot(kind='bar')
plt.axhline(mean)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

PS - I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: please post a sample of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried recreating what I think is your problem, using random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a':np.random.randint(0,10,100),
        'b':np.random.randint(0,10,100),
        'c':np.random.randint(0,10,100),}
)

df.groupby('a').sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: barplot]

I think your problem is, that this line:

```
mean = df.groupby('a').sum().mean()
```

returns the mean for every group:

```
b    48.7
c    42.1
dtype: float64
```

Then, you call

```
plt.axhline(mean)
```

Which wants to plot exactly one line, but you give it several. You can do two things:

1. either, plot the mean for every group:

   ```
   for m in mean:
       plt.axhline(m)
   ```
2. or, calculate the mean of the means, and plot that:

   ```
   plt.axhline(np.mean(mean))
   ```